# my app keeps stopping in android emulator

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

i'm trying to code a login/register program in android studio , and i followed this tutorial on youtube :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RewvdB82PY
 but my app keeps crashing.

my logcat looks like this:

```
   04-29 00:01:58.833 10970-10970/com.myproject.az.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.myproject.az.myapp, PID: 10970
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myiscaeproject.az.myapp/com.myiscaeproject.az.myapp.activities.MainLogIn}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                             at com.myiscaeproject.az.myapp.activities.MainLogIn.initViews(MainLogIn.java:54)
                                                                             at com.myiscaeproject.az.myapp.activities.MainLogIn.onCreate(MainLogIn.java:46)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: are you using TextInputEditText  ?

Comment: put java code here

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

It tells you, you are trying to cast an object of type `TextInputEditText` to a `TextInputLayout`.

Now, look at the next line:

```
at com.myiscaeproject.az.myapp.activities.MainLogIn.initViews(MainLogIn.java:54)
```

it tells you, it happens in line 54 of your `MainLogIn.java` file.

Learn to read stack traces, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your error/exception you can see `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

I guess in your activity file you are trying to assign TextInputEditText to TextInputLayout. Please check where you are assigning using findViewById.